# Azure Datafactory copy activity ending when encountering null line

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to copy from a table in Microsoft Dynamics Marketing to blob storage, the ADF job seems to be ending when encountering a null line despite there being succeeding records which it is not reading. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Do you have anymore details? An example record set? The input dataset JSON?

Comment: Hi Paul,

 The table is the EmailTrackingResults table, the following is my dataset

{
    "name": "AzureBlobDatasetTemplate",
          "type": "AzureBlob",
        "linkedServiceName": "AzureStorageLinkedService",
        "            "format": {
                "type": "JsonFormat",
                "filePattern": "setOfObjects"
            },

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/marketing-customer-center/odata-feeds-overview.aspx#EmailTrackingResult.

It was working ok before, but lately truncated before retrieving all records, with my last retrieved line being a null.